# how to group multiple rows from single table and get all record within given range

Tags: php, mysql, yii, range, between

I want all the hostel within the given price range from my hostel's table.
price is stored into four different rows like price one share, price two shares, price three shares, price more share,

```
public function actionNearbyHostel($min,$max,$types,$lat,$long){   
    $latitude = $lat;
    $longitude = $long;
    $type = $types;
    $max_price = (int)$max;
    $min_price = (int)$min;
    $hostels = Hostels::find ()->select("*,(6371 * 
        acos(cos(radians({$latitude}))* 
        cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`log`) - radians({$longitude})) + 
        sin(radians({$latitude})) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) AS distance")
            ->having("distance<:distance")
            ->addParams([ 
                ':distance' => 5 
            ])->where([
                'status' => Hostels::ACTIVE,
                'type' => $type
            ])->andWhere(['between','price_one_share',$min_price,$max_price])
    ->all();
    return $this->render('filterhostel',[
        'hostels' => $hostels,
    ]);
}
```

This is my action where I already have written

```
andWhere(['between','price_one_share',$min_price,$max_price])
```

like this, I want to include the remaining three rows and get my result.

this is my table row image
http://www.clipular.com/posts/4991398571671552?k=Lud1W4LGJe5hSxOsl2ao7VOGguI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some homework, I found the answer

```
 public function actionNearbyHostel($min,$max,$types,$lat,$long){   
    $latitude = $lat;
    $longitude = $long;
    $type = $types;
    $max_price = (int)$max;
    $min_price = (int)$min;
    $hostels = Hostels::find ()->select("*,(6371 * acos(cos(radians({$latitude}))* 
    cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`log`) - radians({$longitude})) + 
    sin(radians({$latitude})) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) AS distance")
    ->having("distance<:distance")
    ->addParams([ 
    ':distance' => 5 
    ])->where([
    'status' => Hostels::ACTIVE,
    'type' => $type
    ])->andWhere(['or',
    ['between','price_one_share',$min_price,$max_price],
    ['between','price_two_share',$min_price,$max_price],
    ['between','price_three_share',$min_price,$max_price],
    ['between','price_more_share',$min_price,$max_price]
    ])
    ->all();
    return $this->render('filterhostel',[
        'hostels' => $hostels,
    ]);
}
```